# Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

Tags: anaconda

I get this  error:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed
```

I tried to reinstall anaconda again and again as well as windows 10 but no result...
can you help me to fix this issues...
thank you

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do? E.g. install a package. What command did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I was issuing this when updating `pandas` inside a `HDICluster`. This is a known issue with Conda 4.7.11. The solution which works for me was running the follow lines, as described at [MDN](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwioxIqp_7_mAhWaIbkGHXMTBDcQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.msdn.microsoft.com%2FForums%2Fen-US%2F12c2f3ce-2baa-494e-83b2-b2f4fe6fe0d3%2Fhdinsight-spark-installing-extra-python-dependencies-using-conda-hangs-on-quotcollecting%3Fforum%3Dhdinsight&usg=AOvVaw3GdfzEUmh0ecT8UEuTMfnH)

```
rm /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir*
wget https://gregorysfixes.blob.core.windows.net/public/subdir_data.py -P /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/
```

I am not sure, but I think update `anaconda` can work too. To update `anaconda`:

```
conda update -n base conda
```